# Listview lag when scrolling, and crash when add item

Tags: java, android, listview, scroll, crash

I have a custom listview with a button to add more elements
but when I add and element the app crash, but when I restart I find that the element is added, (rarely it doesn't crash)

And i

I use custom adapter

```
 class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    ArrayList<ListItem> listItems = new ArrayList<ListItem>();

    CustomAdapter(ArrayList<ListItem> list){
        this.listItems = list;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return listItems.get(position).name;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item,null);

        TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView lastm = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.last);
        TextView time = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.time);
        CircleImageView pic= (CircleImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.pic);

        name.setText(listItems.get(i).name);
        lastm.setText(listItems.get(i).lastm);
        time.setText(listItems.get(i).time);
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(listItems.get(i).pic,0,listItems.get(i).pic.length);
        pic.setImageBitmap(bmp);




        return view;
    }
}
```

and when I add an element the app crashs

```
add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    EditText editText=(EditText) mView.findViewById(R.id.name);
                    String name=editText.getText().toString();
                    boolean result=myDataBase.insertData(imageViewToByte(img),name,"no messages yet","");
                    if (result) {
                        Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this, "Saved in DATABASE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        viewLastData();
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
```

Comment: "crash" ..; do you have a stacktrace of such a crash?

Comment: Can you add your xml code pls ?

Comment: Stulktuske I don't get you, "stacktrace?"

Comment: That means the log of the errors

Comment: I think you should use Picasso for image and RecyclerView for list.

Answer (score 0):

If your ListView lags it's because you used `wrap_content` for the listView's *layout_height*. It forces your ListView to count all the items inside and it has a huge performance impact.

So replace `wrap_content` by `match_parent` to avoid those lags.

**EDIT**: Use a ViewHolder pattern too in your `Adapter`, see [this link](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html#ViewHolder).

Here is an example:

```
// ViewHolder Pattern
private static class ViewHolder {
    TextView name, status;
}

@Override @NonNull
public View getView(int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_name);
        holder.status = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.another_text);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    // Then do the other stuff with your item
    // to populate your listView
    // ...

    return convertView  
}
```

Comment: I changed it to match_parent but I still have the same problem